# Copy subfolder from git repo A to git repo B, without delete folder tree

Tags: git, repository, devops

i´m need to copy one subfolder **from one repo A** **to many other repos (B,C,D,E etc...) with the same structure.**
Example: **`<repoA>/one/two/three/`**
**`<repoB>/one/two/three/`**
**`<repoC>/one/two/three/`**
I need to copy, for example, the subfolder three from `<repoA>` and replace the others "three" subfolders to the others repos (repoB, RepoC, etc) **without loose the folders** /one/two/ tree and **keeping the history, commits from A to others.** Its like a mirroring, How can i do it. I´ve looking for this in whole internet but cant find it.

Comment: it looks like a use case for submodules, but your question is a bit hard to understand. Can you take time to describe your requirements more clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

1. git clone --bare <repoA_URL>.git
2. cd <repoA_URL>.git
3. git push --mirror <repoB_URL>.git

Comment: Thanks for the answear but this repo cant be cloned. Because in the other repos has other folders with other jobs.